# How to render array in react?

Tags: reactjs

all. I am new in learning React.js.

I had no problem to render data from

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "user525",
"email": "user525@gmail.com"
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "user252",
"email": "user252@hotmail.com"
}
]
```

**renderUsers**

```
renderUsers() {
        return this.state.users.map(user => {
            return (
                <tr key={ user.id }>
                    <td>{ user.id }</td>
                    <td>{ user.name }</td>
                    <td>{ user.email }</td>
                </tr>
            );
        })
    }
```

I face problem if my data is like

```
[
  {
    "@attributes":{
       "id": 1,
       "name": "esien525",
       "email": "esien525@gmail.com"
     }
   }
]
```

how to remove the @attributes from the array? Brain had stucked for 3 hours in this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend mutating your `state` by removing `@attributes` from it. Just access the `@attributes` key

```html
return this.state.users.map(userAttributes => {
  let user = userAttributes["@attributes"];
  return (
    <tr key={ user.id }>
        <td>{ user.id }</td>
        <td>{ user.name }</td>
        <td>{ user.email }</td>
    </tr>
  );
})
```

Comment: you used 1 mnute to solve my problem. XD. Thanks a lot!